# Matlab libsvm - couldn't find the vector coefficients w

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

My data matrix is a 1000x65K matrix that contains 500 positive examples and 500 negative examples. My labels are [ones(500,1); -ones(500,1)];

I'm training a linear svm using the following code:

```
cost = 0.1;
epsilon = 2;
gamma = 0.1;
degree = 3;
coef0 = 0;

options_string = ['-s 0 -t 0 ' ' -c ' num2str(cost) ' -p ' num2str(epsilon) ' -g ' num2str(gamma) ' -d ' num2str(degree) ' -r ' num2str(coef0) ' -b 1'];
SVRModel = svm_train(data, labels , options_string);
```

I googled a bit and found that the coefficients vector w can be found using the following code:

```
w = model.SVs' * model.sv_coef;
```

But that gives me one scalar, not a vector of coefficients.

I also tried:

```
w = (SVRModel.sv_coef' * full(SVRModel.SVs));
```

Can someone please clarify how can I find the vector coefficients w?

Thanks,

Gil.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're drowning in trying to do it as a one liner in Matlab. You would need to implement this equation:

[image: equation]

so w is something like

```
w = zeros(1,65000);
for i=1:1000,
    w = w + model.sv_coef(i)*model.SVs(i,:)
end
```

Matlab will do a great job for you of letting you know of the dimensions don't match. Once you get that writing a one liner won't be hard, but it is important to understand the computation, not the one liner.

Comment: thanks for your answer (+1). I'm getting that all the values in the vector w are the same. How can that be? I should have added that my features are either 0 or 1. Thanks.

Edit :also, the coefficients are all 10 or -10 and the support vectors are just the 848 feature vectors.